# Is it possible to force django_sql_explorer to extend my base.html?

Tags: django

I have installed django_sql_explorer package with pip .
I was wondering if it is possible to make \django_sql_explorer to extend my base.html without having all the django_sql_explorer source  code in project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look here: https://github.com/groveco/django-sql-explorer/blob/master/explorer/templates/explorer/base.html you'll see that django-sql-explorer defines an `explorer/base.html` from which other templates override. So, if you want to use your own `base.html` create a directory named `templates/explorer` inside one of your apps and add a `base.html` there (this will override the django-sql-explorer's one).

Please keep in mind that this `base.html` can't be the same as your own site's `base.html` because you need to respect the block names that django-sql-explorer actually defines so that content will be visible.